# Installing paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to install paramiko with python 2.7 but pip install fails because cryptography requires python 3 and above:

```
error in cryptography setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version < '3'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in cryptography setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version < '3'
```

i manually installed cryptography for 2.7 and still can't install paramiko using both pip and a downloaded .tar file like "paramiko-2.0.2.tar" giving me the same error

any idea how can i install this module?

thank you

Comment: tried multiple .whl files and versions of paramiko all fail with the same error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is fix for the situation, but I was also facing same issue while installing paramiko yesterday, so I checked my development environment and installed same version of those packages. In my development environment I had below versions installed,
cryptography = 1.9
paramiko = 2.2.1
It worked for me, let me know if it doesn't work for you.
NOTE : install cryptography 1.9 manually, otherwise while installing paramiko 2.2.1 you'll get the same error.